# Is there any mt-3 pt-3 in Ant Design

Tags: antd

I'm new in Ant Design. In bootstrap, there are className like "mt-3 mx my-3" for making margin spacing.

In antd, is there any method or classNames like this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Nope `antd` itself provides you with functional components, grid and layout system.

However, each component supports `className` property and you can connect for example tailwindcss https://tailwindcss.com/ and use classes from it.

```js
<Title className="mb-0 mt-3">Introduction</Title>
```